# If + past participle

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

In my ATM card , it said : " This is a property of... **If found**, please return to..."
The meaning is clear, but I've never seen a grammar structure like that. Can you tell me what that is ?  Can I use the same with other verbs i.e if broken, if damaged..?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly! The **past participle** can go with the conditional *if*.

> If found, please return to... 
>   If broken, we won't take it back.... 
>   If damaged, you cannot return it.... and so on...

Comment: +1 You might add that this is only acceptable in notices such as OP describes, or signs. In discursive prose, these are all dangling modifiers: they do not modify the nearest NP :)